# Flutter: accessing a future value inside a GridView Stream element

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter GridView based on a Firestore stream. For each element of the Grid, I wish to check some status using a Future value by accessing Firebase doc. The code is as follows

```
...

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> {
  stream: db.collection('coll1').orderBy('field1').snapshots(),
  builder: : (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      return GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
            //
            // here is where I would like the future value
            bool exists = checkIfExists(doc.id);
            // 
            // and use the value in the card below
            //
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(doc.get('field1')),
                onTap: () {...},
              ),
            );
          }).toList());
        }
      },
   );
   .....

Future<bool> checkIfExists(id) async {
    ...
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await db.collection('coll2').doc(id).snapshot();
    return doc.exists ? true : false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot await for futures to complete inside build methods in general in Flutter. You can use another Future builder\stream builder inside your current stream builder. Or chain both functions from the start, and show results based on the results of your last <bool>function.

Comment: Thanks @HuthaifaMuayyad. Being new to flutter I was wondering if there was a better declarative way of achieving that.

Comment: Let me try to do it and post an answer, it'll be clearer.

Comment: *"Being new to flutter I was wondering if there was a better declarative way of achieving that."* - yes it is: check [Stream.asyncMap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) method